# Replace umlaute with double backslash for LaTex

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I want to replace the german umlaute `ä, ü, ...` with `\\"a, \\"u, ...`.

**Example:**

The string `Ägypten` should be converted to `\\"Agypten`. 
But `gsub` won't let me:

```
gsub('Ä','\\"A','Ägypten')
> [1] "\"Agypten"
gsub('Ä','\\\"A','Ägypten')
> [1] "\"Agypten"
gsub('Ä','\\\\"A','Ägypten')
> [1] "\\\"Agypten"
```

*By the way: I need this for `knitr, tikZ, and Xetex`. Unfortunately a `UTF8` solution is not viable for me.*

Comment: You should probably handle this problem in latex instead.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a literal string replacement here bearing in mind that in a literal string replacement, you need 2 `\`s to represent one literal backslash:

```
> s <- gsub('Ä','\\\\"A','Ägypten', fixed=TRUE)
> cat(s)
\\"Agypten>
```

If you use a regex replacement, one needs to use 4 backslashes in the replacement pattern string literal (that is, 2 literal backslashes) to replace with 1 literal backslash.